# Spawn prefab after killing the enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy and a simple script on it (if `hp <= 0`, then the enemy is destroyed). I want the enemy to spawn a prefab after death, which allows you to pick up a gun in the inventory, but if you create it through

```cs
Instantiate(pistolprefab, GameObject.transform);
```

then the gun is created as a "child" of the enemy and is also destroyed with the enemy.

```cs
public GameObject snipprefab;
public GameObject pistolprefab;
public GameObject rocketlauncherprefab;
    
public int TypeOfGun = 0;
private bool gunSpawned = false;
    
public static float HP = 10;
    
public void Start()
{
    
}

public void AddDamage(float damage)
{
    HP -= damage;
    if (HP <= 0)
    {
        if (EnemyHealth.HP <= 0 && gunSpawned == false)
        {
            switch (TypeOfGun)
            {
                case 1:
                    Instantiate(pistolprefab, gameObject.transform);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Instantiate(snipprefab, gameObject.transform);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Instantiate(rocketlauncherprefab, gameObject.transform);
                    break;
            }
            gunSpawned = true;
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to properly indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your object to the different parent using `SetParent()` on your new game object's transform component:

```
GameObject temp = Instantiate(pistolprefab, gameObject.transform);

temp.transform.SetParent(null); // set parent to null if you don't want it to have a parent
```

Make sure to do that, before the original object is destroyed.

Comment: it working, thx,
idk why i dont think about that